# Pronunciation of « peut être »

Tags: prononciation

I know that in « peut-être » the t is pronounced and I was wondering whether the t is still pronounced between the *peut* and the *être* in sentences like « il peut être quelque chose » because it has a different meaning here and I was wondering whether the French distinguish aurally between the two.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you say you always liaise when you pronounce the adverb *peut-être* [pœtɛtʁ].

When using the verb *pouvoir* followed by a vowel sound (not necessarily the letter "e") it is a case of non mandatory liaisons, although I suspect most people would liaise. **I** think I always do but I'm not surprised or shocked, if I hear [sapœɛtʁɛ̃tɛʁɛsɑ̃] or [ilpœavwaʁʁɛzɔ̃], so without a liaison.

Comment: +1 but YMMV, I believe I almost never liaise after a conjugated *pouvoir* ([sapœɛtʁ]) like for example [this singer](https://www.dailymotion.com/video/x2di74j?start=93)

Comment: @jlliagre jolie mélodie ! connaissais pas. Oui difficile de toujours s'écouter parler ! Et peut-être que tu prononces différemment au sud de Montélimar.

Comment: @jlliagre La chanteuse est Québécoise :), la région peut définitivement avoir un impact, je confirme que moi non plus je ne ferais pas la liaison. Peut-être justement pour différencier les deux en général.

Comment: Idem ici, j'ai /pœtɛːtr/ (aussi /ptɛːt/) pour l'adverbe alors que le verbe est /pøɛːtr/ sauf à la lecture à voix haute

Comment: @None La différence ne concerne pas vraiment les liaisons mais le nombre de syllabes. Pour *peut être* c'est /pœɛt(ʁ)/ au nord et  /pœɛtʁə/ au sud (une syllabe de plus) et pour *peut-être* /(p)tɛt(r)/ comparé à /pœtɛːtʁə/ (deux syllabes de plus).

Answer (score 1):

In my variety of French the eu in *peut-être* is more often pronounced as a short [œ] if not dropped completely, whereas in *peut être* it is always pronounced [ø]. So when I read the phrase *peut être*, I tend to emphasize the [ø] and still liaise and pronounce the T.

In practice it's not a phrase that comes up all that often.